# Get Jaccard Similarity by Comparing All Rows in A Pandas Dataframe While Keeping Track of Rows Being Compared

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, nlp, data-processing

Hi I would like to get the Jaccard similarity between all rows in a dataframe.

I already have a jaccard similarity function like the following which is taking in two lists, but I couldn't get my head around how you can keep track of the users for which the comparison is being done.

```
def jaccard_similarity(x,y):
  """ returns the jaccard similarity between two lists """
  intersection_cardinality = len(set.intersection(*[set(x), set(y)]))
  union_cardinality = len(set.union(*[set(x), set(y)]))
  return intersection_cardinality/float(union_cardinality)
```

I would like to run this function against all the rows in the dataframe.

| wordings | users |
| --- | --- |
| apple,banana,orange,pears | adeline |
| banana,jackfruit,berries,apple | ericko |
| berries,grapes,watermelon | mary |

How can I generate an output like the below where I can keep track of the users being compared?

| user1 | user2 | similarity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| adeline | eriko | 0.5 |
| adeline | mary | 0.2 |

Thank you very much for guidance.

```
sentences = ['apple,banana,orange,pears', 'banana,jackfruit,berries,apple']
sentences = [sent.lower().split(",") for sent in sentences]
jaccard_similarity(sentences[0], sentences[1])
```

Output: 0.3333333333333333

Running the above code would makes me get the values that I wanted but I am just stuck on how to keep track of the users being compared in the dataframe if I were to have 100 rows of the data.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), and about [Voting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) and [Accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution is the following:

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd

# copied from OP above
def jaccard_similarity(x, y):
    """ returns the jaccard similarity between two lists """
    intersection_cardinality = len(set.intersection(*[set(x), set(y)]))
    union_cardinality = len(set.union(*[set(x), set(y)]))
    return intersection_cardinality/float(union_cardinality)

# set initial data and create dataframe
data = {"wordings": ["apple,banana,orange,pears", "banana,jackfruit,berries,apple", "berries,grapes,watermelon"], "users": ["adeline", "ericko", "mary"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# create list of tuples like [(wording, user), (wording, user)]
wordings_users = list(zip(df["wordings"], df["users"]))

result = []

# create list of all possible combinations between sets of (wording, user) and loop through them
for item in list(itertools.combinations(wordings_users, 2)):
    similarity = jaccard_similarity(item[0][0], item[1][0])
    data = {"user1": item[0][1], "user2": item[1][1], "similarity": similarity}
    result.append(data)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(result)
df1
```

Returns

[image]